# CoreGraphics prevents frame modifications on other objects?

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, ios7, core-graphics

Just getting started with iOS development, so please forgive my ignorance here. I've also searched for a while without success on this topic, but I'm sure I'm just not searching the right terms.

If I comment out the only line in this first for loop, the next for loop seems to function exactly how I expect. If I leave them both in then, I only see the CG stuff happening and the other objects sit still.

**What does the transformation on the object currentGear have to do with the frame being changed on another object within the same view? Why would performing the transformation invalidate the frame change after it?**

```
for (UIImageView *currentGear in self.imageGearCollection)
{
    currentGear.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentGear.transform, (90*M_PI)/180);
}

for (UIButton *currentCrate in self.buttonCrateCollection)
{
    CGRect rectFrame = currentCrate.frame;

    rectFrame.origin.x += 10;

    currentCrate.frame = rectFrame;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question ?

Comment: @uchuugaka I updated my question to spell out what I thought I previously implied. Why does performing the transformation on one array of objects prevent the other array of objects from moving by having their frame changed?

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't really have anything to do with Core Graphics.

The [*UIView Class Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW5) says this about `frame`:

> Warning: If the `transform` property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

So what you're doing is not really allowed.

Since you're just trying to move the view, not change its size, you can do that by modifying its `center` property instead:

```
CGPoint center = currentCrate.center;
center.x += 10;
currentCrate.center = center;
```

Comment: I believe I understand that, but I don't understand why changing the transform on one object has anything to do with another separate object's frame property.

Comment: something else I wasn't mentioning was I had this code set in a timer. I can turn the transform bit into a repeating animation which works out fine, but if I have the transform of one object prior to changing the frame of another, the frame change is invalidated.